# ¿Cómo agregar íconos fontawesome en React?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo problemas para colocar iconos dentro de un componente en `React`,

```
<i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

intento importar cualquiera pero no se visualizan a que se debe esto, tengo que importar una librería extra ? De que manera pueda solucionarlo?

```
 <div  className='info' style={{backgroundColor:'black', height:'300px'}}>
                <h2>Historia</h2>
                <h2>Enlaces</h2>
                <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i>
    </div>
```

Comment: ¿Cómo emplea la librería?  a través de `npm`  o directamente desde un `cdn` sí es desde el `cdn` debería funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución dentro de un foro, instalas el módulo

```
meteor npm install --save react-fontawesome
```

en el `<head>` de tu proyecto colocas el archivo

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css‌​/font-awesome.min.cs‌​s">
```

y llamas al icono con un componente

```
   import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';
<hr></hr>
                <h1>Gerardo Bautista</h1>
                <h3>Analista/Programador - Desarrollador Web</h3>
                <Rocket/>

    var Rocket = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
          return (
            <FontAwesome
              className='rocket'
              name='rocket'
              size='2x'
              spin
              style={{ textShadow: '0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',color:'lightblue' }}
            />
          );
        }
      });
```